# Angular scope variable update not reflected in UI

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap, angularjs-digest

We are working on an HTML page which makes use of a Bootstrap tooltip on a certain `<span>` tag.  For those who have not heard of tooltip, it is a popup of sorts which appears when hovering over the element to which it is attached.  Here is a screenshot showing the `<span>` in question, and what happens on hover:

[image]

The premise behind adding the tooltip was that in the event that we truncate the text, the tooltip would provide an option for viewing the entire text.

However, we would now like to condtionally show the tooltip *only* when there is no ellipsis in the text.  We defined the `tooltip-enable` property in the `<span>`:

```
<span uib-tooltip="{{someName}}" tooltip-placement="right" tooltip-enable="{{showToolTip}}">{{someNameShortened}}</span>
```

The key thing here is `tooltip-enable="{{showToolTip}}"`, which binds the property to a scoped variable in the controller for this page.  And here is the relevant (and abbreviated) controller code:

```
mainApp.controller('repoListController',['$scope', '$rootScope', ...,
function($scope,$rootScope, ...) {

    $scope.showToolTip = false;

    var repositoryList= function(){
        repositoryService.getRepositoryList(function(data) {
            var repoList = data;                
            repoList.shortenedDisplayName = repositoryService.getShortRepoName(repoList.repoName, DISPLAY_NAME_MAX_LENGTH);
            // if the repository's name be sufficiently large (i.e. it has an ellipsis)
            // then show the tooltip.  Otherwise, the default value is false (see above)
            if (repoList.repoName.length > DISPLAY_NAME_MAX_LENGTH) {
                $scope.showTooltip = true;
            }
        });
    }

    repositoryList();
}]);
```

Based on the research I have done, the common solution for why a change to a scoped variable is not reflected in the UI is to run `$scope.$apply()`, or some variation on this.  Running `apply()`, as I understand it, will tell Angular JS to do a digest cycle, which will propagate changes in the scope to the UI.  However, trying to do an `apply()` from the code which toggles `showToolTip` resulted in errory.  I inspected the value of `$scope.$root.$$phase` while running the code which updates the `showToolTip` variable, and the phase was `digest`.

So now I am at a loss to explain this.  If the code is already in a digest, then why would changes not be reflected in the UI?  Also, if the code is already in digest, then how could I force Angular to sync the changes to the UI?

Comment: Try removing the `{{ ... }}`, ie `tooltip-enabled="showTooltip"`. Interpolation is for strings, not booleans

Comment: @Phil I will try this now.  The thing is, upon inspecting the page I saw `tooltip-enabled="false"`.

Comment: Yes, but the string `"false"` is *truthy*

Comment: @Phil I made the change you suggested, but now I see this in the tag: `tooltip-enable="showToolTip"` ... it clearly isn't `true` or `false`, and it still does not toggle according to the logic in the controller.  Your thoughts?

Comment: There's absolutely no point at looking at the DOM for bound Angular property values. As for it still not working, I'm not sure. How about adding some debugging to the template (just under your element) like `<pre>showToolTip = {{showToolTip | json}}</pre>`?

Comment: OK I just stepped through the JavaScript code, and I verified that when `showToolTip` is set to false, the tooltip is still appearing.  There is a problem with the binding.

Comment: Seems to work OK using the [ui bootstrap plunker demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/W7tgJmeQAJj0fmfT72PR?p=preview). Make sure you have `tooltip-enable="showToolTip"`. I made a typo in my first comment (enable**d** vs enable)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/111821/discussion-between-tim-biegeleisen-and-phil).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two things need fixing...

1. Don't use string interpolation for your boolean `showToolTip`

   ```
   <span uib-tooltip="{{someName}}" tooltip-placement="right" 
         tooltip-enable="showToolTip">{{someNameShortened}}</span>
   ```
2. JavaScript variables / properties are case sensitive. In your `getRepositoryList` handler, you have `$scope.showTooltip`. It should be `$scope.showToolTip` (two capital "T"s)

Crappy Plunker demo ~ http://plnkr.co/edit/W7tgJmeQAJj0fmfT72PR?p=preview